# c# SerialPort - not reading all data send

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have recently created an app that is recieving data send through UART from my STM device. The data I try to send is an array of floats - float[512].
The data is send as **pure binary - not string.** Generally idea is 4xbyte = float.

I am sure that data that I'm sending is good. Checked it with program called "Terminal" and then IEEE 754 Converter.
[My program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDK3U.png)

In program I choose COMport from available and other parameters.
(by default they are my COM adapter parameters). I open connection and then when by STM finishes sending data I'm clicking on "Odebrane" button so it will display data in TextBox

**The problem** is that I'm not recieving all data.
And I have no idea what is the cause.

```
private List<float> lista = new List<float>();
private float[] fDane = new float[1024];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getAvailablePorts();
        tb_Rx.Text = "Wprowadź parametry transmisji";
        cb_BaudRate.Text = "9600";
        cb_DataBits.Text = "8";
        cb_Handshake.Text = "None";
        cb_Parity.Text = "None";
        cb_StopBits.Text = "One";
    }


    private void SerialP_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

        int size = sp.BytesToRead;
        byte[] bArray = new byte[size];
        float[] fArray = new float[size / 4];
        sp.Read(bArray, 0, size);

        for (uint i = 0; i < size / 4; i++)
        {
            fArray[i] = ByteToFloat(bArray, i); // change 4 bytes to  float
            lista.Add(fArray[i]);            
        }

    }

    private float ByteToFloat(byte[] input, UInt32 i)
    {

        byte[] Array = new[] { input[4 * i], input[4 * i + 1], input[4 * i + 2], input[4 * i + 3] };
        return BitConverter.ToSingle(Array, 0);
    }

    private void bt_transform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float[] fDane = lista.ToArray();
        for(UInt32 i = 0; i < fDane.Length; i++)
        {
            RxPisz(fDane[i]);

        }
    }
```

------------------------- SOLVED ---------------------
changed dataRecieved interrupt handler

```
private void SerialP_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            byte[] bArray = new byte[4*numberOfSamples];
            float[] fArray = new float[numberOfSamples];


            int previouse = counterOfRecBytes;

            counterOfRecBytes += sp.BytesToRead;

            sp.Read(bArray, previouse, (counterOfRecBytes - previouse));



            if (counterOfRecBytes == 4*numberOfSamples)
            {
                for (uint i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; i++)
                {
                    fArray[i] = ByteToFloat(bArray, i); // change 4 bytes to float
                    lista.Add(fArray[i]);
                }
                counterOfRecBytes = 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not reading data at the good speed, try to change BaudRate from 9600 to 19200.

Comment: Well, I tried - it doesn't help.
Generally I can set my UART-RS232 adapter to various speeds.
Shouldn't **SerialPort.BytesToRead** read size of all data I'm sending in one "array" of 8bit frames?